# .bat Merging header.txt to all *.txt files

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I have a file called header.txt I want this file to be prepended (first line) to all *.txt files in the same directory.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
for %%x in (*.txt) do call :merge %%x
goto :eof

:merge
copy header.asc + %1 %1.new
del %1
ren %1.new %1
exit /b
```

Don't call the file `header.txt` though, because you don't want to prepend the header to itself (that's why I called it `header.asc`).

Make a backup before trying ;)

Answer (score 1):

use for loop, and then copy + command.

See copy /? for `copy +` syntax.

See for /? for for syntax.